# How to transfer a random value from one element to another?

Tags: python

I want to create a list of 10,000 elements, and each of them transfers a value to another randomly selected element and repeat for 100,000 times (or more). The distribution of the transferred value can be assigned (e.g. normal or log-normal etc).

What I can think of is using a loop and assign another list to save the transfer values.

Considering the time of running might be very long, is there a way to finish this efficiently?

for example:
1. Initial state:

```
x = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

2. All the elements randomly decrease by a number:

```
x = [4, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

3. I will create another list, x2, to save the changes, this values will be assigned to the elements (but not the exact element this value come from, e.g. x2[0] will never be assigned to x[0]) in x randomly:

```
x2 = [1, 2, 1, 4, 3]
```

4. Finally I might get:

```
x = [7, 7, 7, 2, 2]
```

`x2[1]` and `x2[2]` added to `x[0]`, `x2[3]` to `x[1]`, `x2[4]` to `x[2]`, `x2[0]` to `x[3]` and nothing happened for `x[4]` (this is an example as all things are random).

My current code is shown as below, with fixed values and I cannot exclude x[i] in the selection process.

```
import random

x = [5]*5
x2 = []
# Change the values in list x, and create list x2 to store the changes.
for i in range(len(x)):
    rand_i = random.randint(1,4)
    x[i] = x[i]-rand_i
    x2 = x2+[rand_i]

# Randomly add values in list x2 to elements in list x.
# Do not add x2[i] to x[i].

for i in range(len(x2)):
    ii = random.randrange(len(x2))
    x[ii] = float(x[ii]) + float(x2[i])

print(sorted(x))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer"? Have you tried the naive version and verified that it is indeed too slow? If nothing else, writing that code gives us something to build upon.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you trying to shuffle the elements?

Comment: I think an example would help to understand your problem better.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the comment, I made an example I the question.

Comment: I'm even more confused by your example. How does `x1` become `x2`? What function is being applied?

Comment: @FHTMitchell `X1` does not become `X2`, but I create `X2` to record the value changed in `X1`. To me, it will be created by a for loop.

Comment: Ohhh so `x2` is just the difference between `x` and `x1`? I have no idea what you're trying to convey in "but not the exact element this value come from, e.g. x2[0] will never be assigned to x1[0])". That genuinely makes no sense. Can you also expand on step 4, what chooses which values from `x1` and `x2` to use?

Comment: @FHTMitchell Yes and I am able to come with some code (not exactly the same) to demonstrate my idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I've understood the algorithm right. The explanation is in comments in the code:

```
import random

# initial state
x = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
print('step 1:\tx =\t', x)

# decrease each element by random number = create list x2
x2 = [random.randint(1, 3) for _ in range(len(x))]
print('step 2:\tx2 =\t', x2)
x = [vx - vx2 for vx, vx2 in zip(x, x2)]
print('step 3:\tx =\t', x)

while x2:
    # pop element from x2
    v = x2.pop()
    # apply this element to random value in list x
    x[random.randint(0, len(x)-1)] += v

# print final value of list x
print('step 4:\tx =\t', x)
```

This prints (for example):

```
step 1: x =  [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
step 2: x2 = [1, 1, 1, 3, 2]
step 3: x =  [4, 4, 4, 2, 3]
step 4: x =  [5, 4, 4, 8, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks, seemed to be much simpler than mine. Will try it for efficiency, as when loop for 1,000,000 times mine goes pretty slowly.